# How to give default mapping of enum to string using AutoMapper?

Tags: c#, string, enums, automapper

Supposing I have two types: MyEnum and string, I can create a mapping like

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<MyEnum, string>().ConvertUsing(src => src.ToString()));
```

but can I tell AutoMapper to map **any** enum to string by calling `.ToString()`?

Since if I have like 100 enum types and I want to convert all of them to strings by calling `ToString()`, I have to add 100 new lines of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not necessary. It works by default.